# What does output_dim in Keras Dense mean?

Tags: keras

I am a newbie in Deep Learning.By studding this article
[link](https://medium.com/nybles/create-your-first-image-recognition-classifier-using-cnn-keras-and-tensorflow-backend-6eaab98d14dd) .

I cannot understand what does the `output_dim=128` and `output_dim=1` mean???

I would expect as output in final Dense the number of classes=2(Cat/Dog).

Besides from where is the 128???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output_dim is the dimension of the dense embedding.

The choice of 128 in

```
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 128, activation = 'relu'))
```

is quite arbitrary , it just indicate the size of fully connected layer that you prefer. You can change it to another number.

The 1 in

```
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
```

is due to for a binary classification problem, we just require a probability to distinguish the 2 groups. If the probability is at least 0.5, we classify it as a dog, if it is less than 0.5, we classify it as a cat.

If you prefer, you can also set activation function to be softmax and output_dim to be 2 as the last layer though that would not improve the performance.

Comment: i would expect output_dim=2 because of binary results.I imagine a layer with 2 neurons one for class dog and the other for cat....I still don't get the "1" !

Comment: If you know the probability of being a dog for a particular picture is 0.6, do you know the probability of beign a cat?

Comment: Ok ,so you mean that there is only one node in output??

Comment: yes, there is only one node. You might like to experiment with 2 nodes with softmax as well. I do read that the performance could be better.